# exact differential equation concept of definition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

we have learned about exact differential equations.But while redoing that topic I was confused why we are actually defining exact differential equation in some rectangle 'R'? Can someone help me with the concept please.

Answer (score 1):

In general, differential equations may involve functions that are not everywhere defined, or have nasty singularities.  That's not a problem if we only need the solution in some interval rather than everywhere.  For example, consider the differential equation
$$ \dfrac{dx}{x} + \dfrac{dy}{y} = 0$$
which is undefined at $x=0$ and at $y=0$.  It satisfies the condition for an exact equation, but only if you restrict attention to a set such as the first quadrant
$\{(x,y)\; : \; x > 0, \; y > 0\}$.